# Integral of $\sin(t)(1-\sin(t))^{3/2}$

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate

$$\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin(t)(1-\sin(t))^{3/2} \; dt$$

[Wolfram Alpha suggests](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+of+sin%28t%29%2a%281-sin%28t%29%29%5E%283%2F2%29+from+-pi%2F2+to+pi%2F2) a double substitution to get a polynomial, integrating, then resubstituting to get a very complex term. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: x=tan(t/2) bro.

Comment: Resubstituting is unnecessary, we can change the limits of integration. I do not have access to the Alpha step by step. Beside the Weierstrass substitution, we can let $2w=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$. Then $\sin t =\cos 2w=2\cos^2 w-1$ and $1-\sin t=2\sin^2 w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $\sin(t) = x$

$$\implies dx = \cos(t) dt$$

$$\iff dt = \frac{dx}{\cos(t)} = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\sin(t)^2}} = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$.

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin(t)\cdot(1-\sin(t))^{3/2} dt$$
$$=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x(1-x)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
$$=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x(1-x)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}} dx$$
$$=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x(1-x)}{\sqrt{1+x}} dx$$

substitute $1+x=y$

$$=\int_0^2 \frac{(y-1)(2-y)}{\sqrt{y}} dy$$

expand powers to yield elementary integrals

$$= -\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{5}$$